# ¿Cómo mostrar un efecto de cargando.. antes de cargar el contenido fetch API con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una `API` donde la petición la hago desde un archivo `Javascript` utilizando `fetch`.

el asunto o el problema es que en ocasiones son muchos los datos que necesito mostrar y eso demora un poco en cargar e incluso yo sabiendo que esta haciendo el proceso por abajo aveces dudo si esta ejecutando o no, entonces me gustaría que mientras el `API fetch` hace todo el proceso, primero se muestre un efecto de spinner de un gif, png o un diseño con `CSS` lo que sea, lo único que quisiera es saber como poder hacer, que utilizar y el resto lo podría hacer yo.

CÓDIGO (es un ejemplo no son los datos que estoy usando):

```js
fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((datos) => {
    var cov19 = datos.Global
    cadena = `<tr>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewConfirmed}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalConfirmed}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewDeaths}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalDeaths}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewRecovered}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalRecovered}"></td>
    </tr>`
    document.getElementById('generar_datos').innerHTML= cadena
})
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-borderd table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Nuevos Confirmados</th>
                <th>Total Confirmados</th>
                <th>Nuevos Fallecidos</th>
                <th>Total Fallecidos</th>
                <th>Nuevos Recuperados</th>
                <th>Recuperados</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="generar_datos"></tbody>
    </table>   
</div>
```

> La idea es casi la misma uso `fetch` obtener y luego mostrar datos pero de otra forma (utilizo `for` y `foreach`, no se si eso haga una diferencia).
> lo que estoy mostrando (código) es un ejemplo no es lo que estoy haciendo realmente, fue lo primero que se me ocurrió.

Espero me puedan ayudar con esa duda Gracias!

Comment: Antes de ejecutar la función fetch, coloca el contenido que quieres que sirva como loader, y cuando lleguen los datos lo quitas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregar un estilo de cargando y dependera de donde quieres que se vea desde un gift hasta una imagen vectorial, y adicional a esto el truco para esto es usar las bondades del [**.then()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/then).

La idea de usar el [**.finally()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/finally) es por si falla el servicio tambien devolvamos los estilos como estaban

```js
const $tabla = document.getElementById('generar_datos');
const $cargando = document.getElementById("cargando");
$cargando.style.display = 'block'
$tabla.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((datos) => {
      var cov19 = datos.Global
      cadena = `<tr>
          <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewConfirmed}"></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalConfirmed}"></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewDeaths}"></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalDeaths}"></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewRecovered}"></td>
          <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalRecovered}"></td>
      </tr>`
      $tabla.innerHTML= cadena
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  .finally(()=>{
    $cargando.style.display = 'none';
    $tabla.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
  })
```

```html
<div id="cargando" style="display:block" >Cargando</div>
<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-borderd table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Nuevos Confirmados</th>
                <th>Total Confirmados</th>
                <th>Nuevos Fallecidos</th>
                <th>Total Fallecidos</th>
                <th>Nuevos Recuperados</th>
                <th>Recuperados</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="generar_datos"></tbody>
    </table>   
</div>
```

> ***En javascript usualmente se antepone el signo '`$`' para saber que la variable es un elemento del DOM***

Comment: muchas gracias, este me resulto mas practico sencillo y eficiente.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `await` y controlar de forma clara y sencilla cuando ha finalizado la carga de datos, poniendo un Spinner o algún texto que informe al usuario y ocultándolo una vez los datos hayan sido cargados.

```js
const cargarDatos = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
    const datos = await response.json();
    
    // Fuerzo artificialmente a que dure más para que se pueda observar el Spinner
    await accionAsincrona();
    
    var cov19 = datos.Global;
    cadena = `
        <tr>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewConfirmed}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalConfirmed}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewDeaths}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalDeaths}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewRecovered}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalRecovered}"></td>
        </tr>`

        // línea ocultando el spinner
    document.getElementById("spinner").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('generar_datos').innerHTML= cadena;
}

const accionAsincrona = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });   
}

cargarDatos();
```

```css
.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent black transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div id="spinner">
  <div class="lds-dual-ring">&nbsp</div>
</div>
  
  <table id="generar_datos">
  
  </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Si quieres seguir usando promesas en vez de usar `async` y `await`:

```js
fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(async (datos) => {
            // Fuerzo artificialmente a que dure más para que se pueda observar el Spinner
        await accionAsincrona();
        
        var cov19 = datos.Global;
        cadena = `<tr>
            <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewConfirmed}"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalConfirmed}"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewDeaths}"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalDeaths}"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewRecovered}"></td>
            <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalRecovered}"></td>
        </tr>`;
        
        // línea ocultando el spinner
            document.getElementById("spinner").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('generar_datos').innerHTML= cadena;
        
        // Añadir línea de código ocultando el mensaje de cargando
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));


const accionAsincrona = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });   
}
```

```css
.lds-dual-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-color: black transparent black transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div id="spinner">
  <div class="lds-dual-ring">&nbsp</div>
</div>
  
  <table id="generar_datos">
  
  </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No son lo mismo, son diferentes tipos de sintaxis para tratar con la asincronicidad en JS. Sin embargo, mientras que una promesa permite capturar un error mediante la claúsula `catch`, `await` no. Para capturar un error usando `await` deberás envolver el bloque de código que lo ejecuta en un `try-catch`.

Comment: Está claro que se ejecuta una Promesa detrás, pero la sintaxis es diferente y el comportamiento no es el mismo por lo anteriormente mencionado. Async y await sirve para que el código quede más limpio y se sienta como si fuera síncrono, evitando situaciones cómo el [Callback Hell](https://blog.avenuecode.com/callback-hell-promises-and-async/await) y facilitando la labor de tratar con la asincronicidad, por ello figura en la respuesta.

Comment: Realmente hacía referencia a usar la sintaxis para manejar Promesas en ES5 respecto a la de ES6

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente puedes tener un elemento que contenga tu elemento de carga, sea un gif o una animación con CSS (como en el ejemplo) y lo que haces es mantenerla oculta con `display: none` ese debe ser su estado por defecto, luego cuando ejecutes tu función para traer datos justo antes que esta se ejecute cambias la propiedad del `display` por algo visible, en este caso `flex`, pero bien podría ser alguno de los otros valores de `display`. Una vez se termine la carga vuelves a ocultar tu contenedor de la animación.

Para tu caso tendrías que hacer envolver `fetch` en una función así:

```
function fetchData() {
  /* Mostrar contenedor de carga */

  fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((datos) => {
    var cov19 = datos.Global;
    cadena = `<tr>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewConfirmed}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalConfirmed}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewDeaths}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalDeaths}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.NewRecovered}"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="${cov19.TotalRecovered}"></td>
    </tr>`;
    document.getElementById('generar_datos').innerHTML = cadena;

    /* Ocultar contenedor de carga */
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo funcional

```js
function fetchData() {
  const loader = document.getElementById('loader');

  loader.style.display = 'flex';

  setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.display = 'none';
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.loader-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: cadetblue;
}

.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}
.loader {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 88px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
}
.loader:before {
  left: -1.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 1.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
@keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="fetchData()">Cargar datos</button>
  <div class="loader-container" id="loader">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actualizo la respuesta de @Sergio.

**Hay que tratar siempre el caso de error**.

Definiendo las siguientes funciones,

```
const showLoading = _ => {
    // Aquí se muestra el GIF, PNG
    // spinner, etc ...
}

const showError = error => {
    // Aquí se muestra el error
    // (si se necesita...)
}

const showData = data =>  {
    // Aquí se tratan los datos obtenidos
    // por la llamada HTTP
}

const hideLoading = _ => {
    // Aquí se oculta de nuevo
    // el PNG, GIF, etc.
}
```

La función principal quedaría del siguiente modo.

```
const load = async _ => {
    showLoading();

    try {
        const response = await fetch('...');
        const data = await response.json();
        showData(data);
    } catch (e) {
        showError(e);
    }

    // Haya excepción o no, el "loading" debe desaparecer.
    hideLoading();
}
```

Con sintaxis `then` y `catch`

```
const load = _ => {
    showLoading();
    fetch(`...`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(showData)
        .catch(showError)
        .then(hideLoading); // Haya excepción o no, el "loading" debe desaparecer.
}
```

Y finalmente, para nota. Usar un *decorator pattern* para la separación de lógicas.

```
const wrapWithLoading = callback => 
    async _ => {
        showLoading();
        await callback();
        hideLoading();
    }

const load = wrapWithLoading(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('...');
        const data = await response.json();
        showData(data);
    } catch (e) {
        showError(e);
    }
});
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: esta opción "actualizada" de la otra respuesta es buena, gracias!